# Samba stops working raspbian

Tags: raspbian, samba

I have setup samba server on raspbian os. It is working well on some android devices , however while writing from samsung j2 and s8 edge it copies some of the part of any file and just stuck there forever and samba also stuck there itself, after this none of samba clients are able to see or copy anything to the samba share untill a reboot is done. I have searched every topic of every forum but not have found a solution to this. I have tested file Manager app for smb client on android device and many other. samba working fine with iphone and mac os high sierra only some android devices are creating problem.

Comment: have you checked the samba log files - perhaps there's information there regarding errors?

Comment: i checked both the logs smbd and nmbd and have nothing found regarding any error. I think it got stuck at some packet and not forwarding since then.